# How to connect the users table to the roles table (using the table user_roles)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to create a basic database for user authentication. So far, every user has a name, a password and a role. I've found this somewhere on the Internet, which looks quite promising:

```
create table if not exists users (
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  username varchar(100) not null,
  password binary(60) not null,
  primary key(id),
  unique(username)
);

create table if not exists roles (
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  role varchar(100) not null,
  primary key(id),
  unique(role)
);

create table if not exists user_roles (
  user_id int unsigned not null,
  role_id int unsigned not null,
  unique(user_id, role_id),
  index(user_id)
);
```

But... if I would create new users, how would I fill the `user_roles` table? I have a feeling there is some "automatic way" to do this, but I have totally no idea (being a database noob :-)). How could I somehow connect a user to a role?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would first populate the `roles` table. Then, add a user to the `users` table. Then, taking the ID from the `users` table, you want to associate it with an ID from the `roles` table inside of the `user_roles` table. Like so:

```
---- Users Table ---------
ID | UserName | Password
 1 | Test     | *****
--------------------------

---- Roles Table ---------
ID | Role
 1 | Test_Role
 2 | Another_Role
--------------------------

---- User Roles Table ---------
UserID | RoleID
     1 |      1
     1 |      2
-------------------------------
```

This is done for a "Many To Many" relationship. It's also called "Normalizing" your database.

Comment: +1 What if a user can only have one role? Do I then need the users_roles table at all?

Comment: No, you don't need it. Just add a `RoleID` field to the `users` table and associate that way. No need for an extra table for one role.

Answer (score 1):

For each user, you simply insert one row in the user_roles table for every role you want to assign to that given user. There's nothing automatic about it. It's a many-to-many relationship.